# Wrapping multiple similar mongoose schemas into a single schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a server which stores records representing Objects, and which uses Mongoose to manage these records. I want to be able to query/update/etc. all objects with a simple API (i.e. a single endpoint). Different types of Objects have some identical attributes, and some different attributes, so a single, ***static*** Object schema won't do. Instead, I still want to have a single schema, but I want to be able to change it slightly by adding/deleting fields when I create each new Object, with the fields which are/aren't present depending on the type of the Object. I don't want a mixed schema, because I want error validation for each type of Object. I want a single schema (as opposed to a different schema for each type of Object) so that I can just do

```
Object = mongoose.model('Object', ObjectSchema);
Object.findOne({objectType: "type1"}, function(err, model) {
    ...
});
```

So basically, I want field validation, while still maintaining some flexibility for attributes, and a single point to query/update/etc. my Object records. If I change the schema with each new Object, recompile it into a model, and create a new instance of that model, will all the instances of the different models (compiled from different modified versions of the same schema) still be queryable as above?

Obviously, I'm new to Mongoose. I just talked a lot about the schema here, and I honestly don't know whether I should have used the word "model" in place of "schema" in some places. I just don't know how I can accomplish all of this. Let me know if I make no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are successfully using the mongoose model inheritance and discriminator functionality for a very similar scenario. See here for an example:

http://www.laplacesdemon.com/2014/02/19/model-inheritance-node-js-mongoose/

You might also be able to use this plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-schema-extend

Comment: Geeze... this is an instance of a serious inability to correctly word my question. Had I just searched for "schema inheritance", I would have found tons of answers. Thanks!

Comment: The first of two links is dead at the moment. Could you include your proposed solution within the answer? @reto